# select and determined by multiple row value

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table people, a table fruit and a table likes.

```
People              fruit               likes
+-----+--------+    +-----+---------+   +-----+-----+
| pid | people |    | fid |  name   |   | pid | fid |
+-----+--------+    +-----+---------+   +-----+-----+
|  1  | Mary   |    |  1  | appple  |   |  1  |  1  |
|  2  | Tom    |    |  2  | orange  |   |  2  |  1  |
|  3  | John   |    |  3  | banana  |   |  2  |  2  |
|  4  | George |    |  4  | coconut |   |  2  |  3  |
...
```

I want to make a query that can search for people who likes apple and orange:

```
Result
+----------+---------------
| People   |  likes
+----------+---------------
| Tom      | apple, orange, banana
```

Actually, I also like to know `how to make the same output above but with different conditions` say people who likes orange but not apples or people who does not like banana, etc.

Comment: this is a basic sql query you can try yourself

Comment: I tried... anyway I got my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   people
FROM     People
    JOIN likes USING (pid)
    JOIN fruit USING (fid)
GROUP BY pid
```

Then:

1. people who likes apple and orange

   ```
   HAVING   SUM(name='apple') AND SUM(name='orange')
   ```
2. people who likes orange but not apples

   ```
   HAVING   SUM(name='orange') AND NOT SUM(name='apple')
   ```
3. people who likes orange but not apples

   ```
   HAVING   NOT SUM(name='banana')
   ```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96400/1).

Comment: Good! That works:) Infact, I spent whole day with a bunch of INNER RIGHT and LEFT JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT. Getting very frustrated anyway:(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.people, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name)
FROM people p INNER JOIN likes l ON p.pid = l.pid
    INNER JOIN fruit f ON l.fid = f.fid
WHERE p.id = 2
GROUP BY p.people
```